# SQL query in linq to sql, group by trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

The idea here is to add up all the ingredients from all of the recipes. This is my query

```
SELECT IngredientName,sum(Amount) as Amount,Unit 
FROM RecipeIngredients Join Ingredients ON RecipeIngredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientsID
GROUP BY IngredientID,IngredientName,Unit
ORDER BY IngredientName
```

It works great. No issues. I'm getting confused with the linq to sql syntax.
This is what I have so far.

```
using (lDataContext db = new lDataContext())
        {
            return (from ri in db.RecipeIngredients join i in db.Ingredients on ri.IngredientID equals i.IngredientsID   

                   group new {ri,i} by new {i.IngredientsID,i.IngredientName,ri.Unit } 
                   into table
                   select new {
                      Name = table.IngredientName
                      Unit = table.Unit
                      Amount = table.Sum(i.amount) } 
                      ).ToList();
        }
```

Can somone please help with my syntax?

Comment: Have you looked for group by examples and read the documentation? Trust me this is easy stuff and you will learn more by looking this stuff up

Comment: where is the documentation?

Comment: Come on, there is a search function here for examples, and there is Google for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using LINQ to Entities but just LINQ to SQL,

For translating SQL to LINQ,

1. Translate subselects as separate variables
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (DISTINCT, TOP, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (new { }) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a join variable and doing another from from the join variable followed by .DefaultIfEmpty().
6. Replace COALESCE with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. SELECT * must be replaced with select range variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
8. SELECT flds must be replaced with select new { ... } creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.